Unable to uninstall extensions
When I uninstall an extension in VS Code it gets automatically reinstalled after a few seconds. I have settings sync turned on (including extensions) but I would expect it to understand that I don't want those extensions anymore.
If I turn off settings sync I can successfully remove extensions. However as soon as I turn it back on, instead of it syncing my local changes to the cloud, it just reinstalls all extensions.
How can I fix this issue?

Okay, in the end I fixed the issue by clearing all cloud synced settings and then re-enabling syncing afterwards. This time when I went on to uninstall extensions these changes actually synced to the cloud correctly.


In VS command line run Ctrl+Shift+P
search for Settings Sync: Show Settings



add ignored extensions

{
    "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
        
    ]
}


unintsall the extensions

